# JOIN, ORDER BY and GROUP BY in same statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables - results and contestants. Result table cointains

- result_id (PK)
- resul_contestant (who scored this)
- value (how much did he scored)
- result_discipline(where he scored this)

contestants table cointains

- contestant_id (PK)
- contestant_name
- contestant_category

What I want to do is to select results for all contestants, but I only want to show one result per contestant - the highest (lowest) one.
So far I managed to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM contenstants
JOIN results ON result_contestant = contenstant_id
WHERE result_discipline = 1 AND contestant_category = 1
ORDER BY value DESC
GROUP BY contenstant_id;
```

However, this gives me syntax error. If I delete the GROUP BY line, I got results ordered from highest, but if any of the contestants scored in this discipline more than once, I got all of his scores.

If I delete the ORDER BY line, I got only one result per contestant, but it returns the first record in db, not the highest one.

How to fix this command to be valid? Also, there are some less_is_better disciplines, where I want the lowest score, but as far as I could use the ORDER BY on final query, it should be achieved by replacing DESC with ASC.
Thanks.

Comment: I started to give a ROW_NUMER() answer, but then realized that this is MySQL, and I don't think MySQL has this window function yet. However, that should point you in the right direction. Also see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/mysql-and-window-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `group by`.  Using `select *` with `group by` just doesn't make sense.  Instead, use a *filter* to get the row you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM contenstants c JOIN
     results r
     ON r.result_contestant = c.contestant_id
WHERE r.result_discipline = 1 AND c.contestant_category = 1 AND
      r.value = (select min(r2.value)
                 from results r2 
                 where r2.result_contestant = r.result_contestant and
                       r2.result_discipline = r.result_discipline
                )
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

Note: I'm not sure if you want `min()` or `max()` in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. However, I noticed that if a contestant had the same score twice, he is shown twice. But I could take care of this in adding results, as there is no reason why having two same records in db.